# Is it all right to call twice AngularJS IPromise.then(...)?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise

I have a TypeScript service written on top of AngujarJS 1.7. One of its methods reads lookup values asynchronously with a promises and caches the result in a JavaScript object. This is fine.
The problem is that multiple calls are made to the same fetch & cache method before the first call  completes and therefore there are multiple un unnecessary HTTP request.
The absolutely minimum code looks like:

```
lookup(lookupType: LookupType): angular.IPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<LookupInfo[]>> {
    return this.api.get(lookupType.contextPath, null, null);
}
```

and then

```
const thePromise = lookup(lookupType);
thePromise.then((response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<LookupInfo[]>) => {
    // ...
    return response.data;
});
```

**My question is**: will a second call to `IPromise.then()` return the same results as the first call without any side effects?

More precisely, in a service written like this, will each second call to `loadData()` with the same parameters reuse the promise made by the first call? Or asked in another way, **is it all right to call .then(...) twice on an IPromise?**

```
class LookupService {

    private readonly lookupPromises: Dictionary<IPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<LookupInfo[]>>> = {};
    private readonly lookupData: Dictionary<LookupInfo[]> = {};

    loadData(lookupType: LookupType, ...callbacks: Function[]): IPromise<LookupInfo[]> {
        if (!this.lookupPromises[lookupType.name]) {
            this.lookupPromises[lookupType.name] = this.lookupApi.lookup(lookupType);
        }
        return this.lookupPromises[lookupType.name].then((response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<LookupInfo[]>) => {
            this.lookupData[lookupType.name] = response.data;
            this.executeCallbacks(callbacks);
            return response.data;
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The linked question refers to a different NPM package Request-Promise which not related to AngujarJS. Moreover the only provided answer in the other question does not address the question: can .then(...) be called twice safely? but just copy/pastes the spec.

Comment: Actually the provided response does answer the question. And the answer is yes, calling then multiple times on a promise returns the value that the promise resolved to.